# DRF add non model fields just to update or create model instance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this issue at the moment with DRF.

I'm recieving extra fields that the model is not using. But those values will define the fields within the model.

```
{
"file_name": "test",
"file_type": "jpg",
"file": basex64 file,
"url_img": null
}
```

And i got this model

```
class imageModel(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   url_img = models.textField(null=False)
```

All I need is to parse file_name and file_type to upload img to create a url_img and upload it on cloud. Is there a way to do this via DRF?

Comment: try using serializer.methodfield

Comment: Yea, i got those but serializer somehow was giving me exceptions.

Comment: is there any specific reason you're not using an ImageField instead of a textfield in your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DRF way of doing this is, explicitly define your *extra fields* in the serializer class.

```
class ImageModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    file_type = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    file = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ImageModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

Here, I have used [**`serializers.CharField`**--(DRF Doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) since all of those data are strings (if not, choose serializer fields accordingly).

Also, setting [**`write_only=True`**--(DRF Doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only) will help us to omit those fields from the response.

Answer (score 0):

As Muhammad answered, you add some Serializers.MethodField() for each of those fields. Also you add this next method inside your Meta class

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
        internal_value = super(ImageSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        file_name = data.get("file_name")
        file = data.get("file")
        file_type= data.get("file_type")
        internal_value.update({
            "file_name": file_name,
            "file": file,
            "content_type": content_type
        })
        return internal_value
```

And retrieve those fields on the create/update method

Comment: `Serializers.MethodField()` ? Ehh... I don't see any reference of the same in the official doc. Did you mean [**`SerializerMethodField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) ?